# Why does block add one more in overlapped P tags?

Tags: html, css

In my code, there are two P tag in there.
And I gave them border.
I think there are two lightblue block in my code 
beacuse there are two p tags.
But if I run this code, There are Three Blocks in there.
I want to know why. 
Please help. Thanks for reading.

```css
p {
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        background: lightblue;
        height: 70px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        line-height: 70px;
   }
```

```html
<html>
    
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <style media="screen">
          p {
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            background: lightblue;
            height: 70px;
            width: 200px;
            border: solid 1px black;
            line-height: 70px;
          }
    
        </style>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <p><p>dddddddddddoo</p></p>
      </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: You can't nest a `<p>` inside a `<p>`, invalid HTML will cause you problems.

Comment: If I am not wrong its because you can't put a `p` inside another `p`. So UA is probably putting one close `</p>` after the first opening `<p>` and one opening `<p>` before the last closing `</p>`. So you get three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
<body>
    <p><p>dddddddddddoo</p></p>
</body>
```

with

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <p>dddddddddddoo</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use your browser's element inspector to look at the actual DOM. The result is:

```
<p></p>
<p>dddddddddddoo</p>
<p></p>
```

A `p` within a `p` is invalid. When the browser encounters the second `<p>`, it implicitly closes the first `p`. Somewhere along the line a third `p` is being implicitly created from your invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest a `<p>` inside a another `<p>` tag. This is invalid HTML. When HTML sees something like this,

It replaces your html with:-

```
 <p> </p>
 <p>dddddddddddoo<p>
 <p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest `<p>` elements. The `<p>` element represents a paragraph. It can't contain block-level elements (including `<p>` itself). If you inspect it in your browser, you will see 3 paragraphs.

`<div>` however is a generic container where content can be inline e.g `<span>` or block-level. Hence `<div>` can contain `<p>` but not the other-way around.

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/862afpo5/1/